# Work and Electric Potential Energy

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, work

A positive charge will move from high potential to low potential, meaning that it will lose electric potential energy. If that is true, how is the work done by the E-Field on this positive charge?

Answer (score 1):

The positive electric charge moves from point of high potential to the point of low potential hence the charge loses its electric potential energy & thus work done by Electric field on the positive charge will be positive as the displacement takes place in the direction of E-field i.e. $\int \vec F\cdot d\vec s=+ve$.